# Should there be a tag named "human ear"?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I have asked two questions related to hearing and missed [human-ear](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-ear) and  [sound](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound), I accept that sound would be more like physics but human ear or ear should be there.

Comment: I created the tags human-ear and hearing, since they fit to the site. I added also descriptions about them such that people know about them. Feel free to improve the wikis

Answer (score 2):

Being used already we have [eyes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eyes) and [vision](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) so I guess the matching set would be [ears](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ears) and [hearing](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hearing) - just used with appropriate zoology/human-biology tags.

Comment: It definitely makes sense to have two tags for each sense and the corresponding anatomical structure.

Comment: I've posted this in another meta discussion about human tags. Should we merge (ear, eye, etc) them to human-physiology to prevent a large number of very specific tags from being created?

Answer (score 0):

One of your questions asks about [mosquitoes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/are-mosquitoes-repelled-by-high-frequency-sound), so "human ear" would be inappropriate. In the [other question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/will-an-animal-be-harmed-by-frequencies-outside-its-hearing-range) claims to be about animals in general, but uses humans as an example. It doesn't seem like "human ear" would be appropriate for either of these questions.

In general, we have [human-anatomy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-anatomy) and [sensation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensation) tags, I think asking for every human body part to have its own tag is a bit overkill. I also agree that [sound](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) belongs in physics, but if it were introduced here I'd favor that it be called something like [sensation-hearing](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensation-hearing) so as to make the superset clear.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the tag [human-ear](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-ear).
It is in line with StackOverflow's current guideline about tags.
They are for instance migrating more tags to [category]-[subcategory] like `asp.net-mvc`.

I agree with Shep that [sound](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) is more to Physics.
It should be [sound-organ](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-organ) or [sound-sensation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-sensation) or something similar.
What is important is that you write a good wiki page about the tag that the user knows the tag really means in my opinion.

Comment: Mmm but given the number of evolution in animals questions we get we could end up with `human-ear`, `dog-ear`, `cat-ear` - even `komodo-dragon-ear`.  I'm not sure that Stack Overflows tagging structure works as well here due to the much higher degree of overlap between tags.  On SO `php-variables` is going to have completely different questions than `java-variables` whereas here to some degree *an ear is an ear*.

Comment: @RoryM Yes - I see some exaggeration going on in your animal examples. I do not believe that *komodo-dragoin-ear* is coming in near future, neither *cat-ear* and *dog-ear* that soon. Probably in 50 years but not now. - A lot more money is put to human research than to the others, since there is a lot to do with humans. Problem is that the researchers are not that centralized. And we need collaboration more. It gives an easy path to human medicine.